# Sharing data between a java application and a different javascript based webapp

Tags: javascript, java

I have a web app running in which there is a java file which fetches the data from a server.Now, I want to access this data as json from a different web app via a javascript file (This file doesn't have the access to the server). So, basically what I want to do is, I will use a get request in the javascript file to obtain the data from a certain url.But what I dont know how to do is, "How do I post the data on that url from the java class which has the access to the data?"

I have some data like { a:"abc", b:"abcd"} in a java file. I want to upload this data to some url so that I can access this json data from a different javascript file using a get request.I am not able to figure out how to do this.

Comment: You want to upload a json through a PUT or Post? I don't really understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I want to upload json using post

Comment: Can you post some code of the server? Do you have a REST-endpoint for the get for example??

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how to answer a question as broad as this one, but I can try and show you what your architecture could look like.

What you call a "java file running on a server" is a *server* application. What you call a "javascript file" I presume is a *client* application (unless it's a node.js app we are talking about here), executing inside a web browser on a *client* machine (e.g. your laptop). The only way you can make them exchange data is via a network protocol.

A simplest protocol for this use case is HTTP. For it to work you will need to make sure your server has a *web-server* functionality. In other words, it should be listening on a port (typically port 80) and should be able to handle requests like "GET http://server-machine-address/data" (i.e. *give me the "data"*).

So if you could make your Java application into a web application which could serve that JSON, then your JavaScript application will be able to grab that JSON from your server via a URL.

From here you can start investigating into these two areas:

- How to write a Java webserver
- How to send and receive HTTP data with JavaScript

Comment: Thank you. This is definitely a good way to tackle the problem.